# disabling chrome translation for javascript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, translation

I am writing a Google Chrome extension.  The targeted pages are written in Russian.  Chrome translates to English.  I can see some inconsistencies appear that seem to be linked to translation.  For example, in the following code I check to see if I am in a particular folder:

```
if (searchResult[0].innerHTML.indexOf("Общая папка")!=-1) alert("You are in Shared Folder."); else (alert(searchResult[0].innerHTML));
```

If I reload the exact same page several times, the result is inconsistent.  Sometimes it detects "Общая папка" but other times it does not.  When it does not detect this phrase, the alert says I am in "Shared Folder" which is the translation for ""Общая папка."  There appears to be no consistency here.  Sometimes I am dealing with the original text (which is preferred) but sometimes I am dealing with crappy translations that are useless for my script because the translations change all the time.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Turning it off would probably fix it but actually the translations are useful and necessary for other aspects of the extension.  I understand that the translation works with some secondary layer of the HTML (I have not researched this very well).  Can I simply refer to the original in my script?

Answer (score 10):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228972/disable-chrome-translation-bar-on-my-website), you can disable translation by placing the following element in the head portion of your web page:

```
Insert this to the head section of your web page.

<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

If you needed to programmatically disable translation, you could add that tag through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about disabling it, but looks like after a translation Chrome adds `class="translated-ltr"` to `<html>` element, so maybe you at least can detect when the page was translated and either warn a user that the extension might not work properly on this page or just disable it.