# Disable Chrome translation bar on my website

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a chat website that is highly dynamic and when visiting it with Google Chrome, the translation bar appears offering to translate the site.  While the translation of dynamic content works better than I'd have expected, it doesn't work well enough for my purpose and doesn't even make much sense in a chat.

Is there some hint I can put into my site so that visitors with Chrome would not see the translation bar?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you explicitly [specify the language](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang) (`<html lang="en">`) of the page, does that override Chrome attempting to auto-detect the language? If Chrome then thought your tagged page was anything but what it's tagged, that sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Insert this to the `head` section of your web page.

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
```

Source: [Meta tag that Google understand - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

Comment: The meta solution only works partially. By partially, I mean that when the page first loads, the translation bar does NOT show, which is what I want. But if I hit 'refresh', then the bar shows up. Is this intentionally?

Comment: i experienced the same effect. nothing can be done about it :(

Comment: You can see the "shows toolbar on refresh" behavior on this page, which has the <meta> tag: http://jsbin.com/ehavan/3 

Alternatively, here's the same page without the <meta> tag: http://jsbin.com/ehavan/2

Comment: Found a little documentation about the meta tag on Google's support site: http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en

Comment: If I understand correctly this will not only disable the bar, but also disable translation of the site at translate.google.com

Comment: cont... I would like to allow the site to be translated, but not encourage it by having this bar show up. So is there a way to just disable the bar, not the translation?

Comment: Interestingly, the "<meta>" tag has no such attribute as "value" - it should be "content".  So whoever is recommending using "value" is recommending a non-standard attribute that just happens to be tolerated.  The correct "content" will definitely work, though.

Comment: @thomasrutter it used to say `value` on Google’s doc.

Comment: It still does, I checked.  I have to assume they made a mistake.

Comment: Note that you have to hard refresh (or close and reopen chrome) before the translate message will disappear; not just a normal refresh.

Comment: Why are people copying the answer get more + ups than the original answer.. ?

Answer (score 28):

The Meta Value should be "**content**", not "**value**"

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

**Update:** I understand that normal meta tags use content to assign the value, however this is a rare case where "value" is actually the correct syntax. i.e.  is confirmed to remove the translate bar.

Comment: +1, it should be content https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Comment: Should be according to the docu, yes. But only "value" works for me (Chrome 28).

Comment: It doesn´t matter which one you use: https://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276

Comment: Good that the other post updated its answer.https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7229002/revisions so this is kind of obsolete now.

Comment: The update here is confusing to me. Is the code in the code block correct or no?

Comment: This works too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome

Answer (score 16):

If you want to block a section (ie: for the original question just the chat window) you can use

```
  class=notranslate
```

From: http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276. 
*If you don't mind your web page being translated by Google Translate, except for a particular section (like an email address, for example), just add class=notranslate to any HTML element to prevent that element from being translated. For example*:

```
Email us at <span class="notranslate">sales at example dot com</span>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is oftentimes a lot more useful than disabling translation altogether as suggested by the other answers. Plus you can still give than class to the entire body tag.

Comment: This is the right answer because it leaves the rest of the site accessible to anyone who doesn't read the original language

Answer (score 4):

If you add the following code

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

inside `<head></head>` it will disable the appearence of the translation bar, **but will also 
disable translation at [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com)**.

For more info check http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en#2641276.

Answer (score 2):

Use the new global attribute. `translate`.

in my case i used it straight into html

`<html lang="en"  translate="no">`

but you can set it on a specific element. example

```
<footer>
   <small>© 2020 <span translate="no">BrandName</span></small>
</footer>
```

[MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate)