# AngularJS - Error : Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using RestAngular to make the Rest Call

---

```
_getMerchantData : function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var service = Restangular
        .all('UrbanLife');
    service
        .one('service')
        .one('api')
        .one('v1')
        .one('businessowner')
        .one('getUserInfo')
        .get()
        .then(
            function(response) {
                countrylist = response;
                deferred.resolve(response);
            },
            function(response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Controller On change function of md-select

---

```
$scope.onActionChange= function(){
    if($scope.welcome.action==="editProfile"){
        $scope.getUserProfile();
    }
};
$scope.getUserProfile=function(){
    merchantService.merchantManager.UpdateUserProfileFlag=true;
    merchantService.merchantManager.emailValidate = false;
    window.location = "#/signup?EditParam="+true;
};
```

Controller of second page which is giving this error. It fetches and shows tha data.     _____________________________________________________________________________

```
/*------registrationCtrl------------*/
app.controller(
    'registrationCtrl',
    [
        '$scope',
        'merchantService',
        'tokenService',
        'photoService',
        '$http',
        '$modal',
        '$location',
        function($scope, merchantService, tokenService, photoService, $http, $modal, $location) {
            $scope.checkIfUpdateProfile=function(){
                var params=$location.search();
                console.log("params.EditParam    "+params.EditParam);
                if(params.EditParam){
                    $scope.editUserProfile=true;
                    $scope.disableName=true;
                    $scope.disableMobile=true;
                    merchantService.merchantManager
                        ._getMerchantData()
                        .then(
                            function(data) {
                                photoService.showImg=true;
                                merchantService.merchantManager.updateData=data;
                                $scope.user = merchantService.merchantManager.merchant;                         merchantService.merchantManager.merchant.updateId=data.user.id;
                                $scope.user.firstname = data.user.firstName;
                                $scope.user.middleName = data.user.middleName;
                                $scope.user.lastName = data.user.lastName;
                                $scope.user.eemail = data.user.emailId;
                                $scope.user.telephone = data.user.contactNumber;
                                photoService.signupPath=data.user.photoUrl;
                                $scope.path = photoService.signupPath;
                                $scope.showImg = photoService.showImg;
                            },
                            function(response) {
                                console.log("Error "+ response);
                            }
                        );
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!---#WelcomePage------->
    <div class="abcdPage" ng-controller="welcomeBusinessCtrl"  ng-init="checkUsertokenwelocme();">
        <md-toolbar class="header" layout="row" layout-align="space-between start">
            <h1 class="logo">UrbanLife</h1>
            <div class="top-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="profile-photo"></div>
                        <span class="welcome-user">Welcome {{username}}!</span>
                        <md-select required name="" ng-model="welcome.action" flex="" ng-change="onActionChange()">
                            <md-option value="editProfile">Edit Profile</md-option> 
                            <md-option value="editPayment">Edit Payment</md-option> 
                            <md-option value="Logout">Logout</md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
    </div>                      
    ________________________________________________________________________________

    <!-- #Signup--->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <md-toolbar class="header dark-header" layout="row" layout-align="space-between start">
        <h1 class="logo">UrbanLife</h1>
        <h5>Already a Merchant? <a href="#/login">SignIn</a></h5>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content ng-controller="registrationCtrl" class="signuppage" ng-init="checkIfUpdateProfile();">
        <div flex layout="column">
            <div class="reg-top"> 
                <h2>
                    <span class="reg-top-title">Basic Information</span>
                    <md-button class="md-primary md-fab md-raised">1</md-button>
                    <span class="hz-line"></span>
                    <md-button
                        class="md-primary md-fab"
                        ng-disabled="
                            (userForm.fName.$dirty && userForm.fName.$invalid) ||
                            (!userForm.fName.$dirty && userForm.fName.$invalid) ||
                            (userForm.email.$dirty && userForm.emailaddress.$invalid) ||
                            (!userForm.email.$dirty && userForm.emailaddress.$invalid) ||
                            (userForm.telephone.$dirty && userForm.telephone.$invalid) ||
                            (!userForm.telephone.$dirty && userForm.telephone.$invalid) ||
                            (userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid) ||
                            (!userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid) ||
                            (userForm.confirm_password.$dirty && userForm.confirm_password.$invalid)||
                            (!userForm.confirm_password.$dirty && userForm.confirm_password.$invalid) ||
                            (imageInvalide)
                        "
                    ng-click="nextPage()"
                >2</md-button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <form name="userForm" novalidate>
            <div layout="row" flex>
                <div layout="column" class="md-padding form-content" flex="60">
                    <label class="match-label">Name<span class="mandate-field"> * </span></label>
                    <div layout layout-sm="column">
                        <md-input-container flex>
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fName" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-maxlength="20" required ng-blur="user.fnamevar=true" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" ng-disabled="disableName">
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container flex>
                            <label>Middle Name</label>
                            <input ng-model="user.middleName" ng-maxlength="20" ng-disabled="disableName">
                        </md-input-container>
                        <md-input-container flex>
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input ng-model="user.lastName" ng-maxlength="20" ng-disabled="disableName"> 
                        </md-input-container>
                        <div class="pointer" ng-show="editUserProfile" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-click="disableName=false; serverSuccess=false;">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>
                    <!-- First Name validation -->
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-show="user.fnamevar">
                        <div ng-messages="userForm.fName.$error">
                            <div  ng-message=" required">first name is required</div>
                            <div  ng-message="maxlength">Your first name is too long</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div layout layout-sm="column">
                        <md-input-container flex="80">
                            <label>Email<span                           class="mandate-field"> * </span></label>
                        <input type="email" name="emailaddress" ng-model="user.eemail"
                            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}"
                            required inuse ng-blur="user.email=true; changeValidateFlag();" ng-disabled="editUserProfile" />
                        </md-input-container>
                        <div ng-if="(user.emailflag)&&userForm.emailaddress.$pending">Checking
                            Availability...</div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-show="user.email">
                            <div ng-messages="userForm.emailaddress.$error"
                                ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div layout layout-sm="column">
                        <md-input-container flex="80">
                            <label>Mobile<span class="mandate-field"> * </span></label>
                            <input ng-model="user.telephone" type="tel" name="telephone" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/" ng-blur="user.telvar=true" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" required ng-disabled="disableMobile"/>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <div class="pointer" ng-show="editUserProfile" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-click="disableMobile=false; serverSuccess=false;">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-show="user.telvar">
                        <div ng-messages="userForm.telephone.$error">
                            <div  ng-message="required">Mobile Number is required</div>
                            <div  ng-message="pattern">Invalid mobile number</div>
                            <div  ng-message="maxlength">Your Mobile number is too long</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <div layout layout-sm="column" ng-hide="editUserProfile">
                        <md-input-container flex="80">
                            <label>Password<span class="mandate-field"> * </span></label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,20}$/" required ng-blur="user.passvar=true" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}" /> </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password Validation -->
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-show="user.passvar">
                        <div ng-messages="userForm.password.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">Password is required</div>
                            <div  ng-message="pattern">Password must contain at least ONE upper case letter, lower case letter, number, & special character</div>
                            <div  ng-message="maxlength">Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</div>
                            <div ng-message="minlength">Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div layout layout-sm="column" ng-hide="editUserProfile">
                        <md-input-container flex="80">
                            <label>Retype Password<span class="mandate-field"> * </span></label>
                            <input ng-model='user.password_verify' type="password" name='confirm_password' required data-password-verify="user.password" ng-blur="user.rpassvar=true" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Retype password -->
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-show="user.rpassvar">
                        <div ng-messages="userForm.confirm_password.$error">
                            <div ng-message="required">Please confirm your password.</div>
                            <div ng-message="passwordVerify">Passwords do not match.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="success-messages" ng-show="serverSuccess">                      
                        <div>Profile information updated successfully.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="success-messages" ng-show="infonotupdated">                         
                        <div>Profile information not updated. Please try Again</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- added for pop up -->
                    <div>
                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="UpdateProfileSpinner.html">
                            <div class="modal-header"> </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" layout="row" layout-align="start start" style="height:100px; overflow: auto; ">
                                <div flex><p>Updating your profile information......</p></div>
                                <div layout="column" layout-align="center start">
                                    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="24"></md-progress-circular>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="row" ng-hide="editUserProfile">
                        <md-button
                            class="md-raised md-primary blue-btn"
                            ng-disabled="
                                (userForm.fName.$dirty && userForm.fName.$invalid) ||
                                (!userForm.fName.$dirty && userForm.fName.$invalid) ||
                                (userForm.emailaddress.$dirty && userForm.emailaddress.$invalid) ||
                                (!userForm.emailaddress.$dirty && userForm.emailaddress.$invalid) ||
                                (userForm.telephone.$dirty && userForm.telephone.$invalid) ||
                                (!userForm.telephone.$dirty && userForm.telephone.$invalid) ||
                                (userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid) ||
                                (!userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid) ||
                                (userForm.confirm_password.$dirty && userForm.confirm_password.$invalid)||
                                (!userForm.confirm_password.$dirty && userForm.confirm_password.$invalid) ||
                                (imageInvalide)
                            "
                            ng-click="nextPage()"
                        >Continue</md-button>
                    </div>
                    <div layout="row" ng-show="editUserProfile">
                        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary blue-btn" ng-click="updateUserProfile()">Save</md-button>
                        <md-button class="cancelbtn md-raised md-primary blue-btn" ng-click="Cancelupdate()">Cancel</md-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="extra-content" layout="column" layout-align="start center" flex="20">
                    <div class="upload-photo" layout="column" layout-align="center top" ng-click="serverSuccess=false;">
                        <span class="file-upd-icon">
                            <img ng-src="{{path}}"  ng-show="showImg"  width="80px" height="80px"/>
                        </span>
                        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                            <span id="upload">Upload Photo</span>
                             <input type="file" id="file" file-model="photo" class="upload" ng-init="imageInvalide=false;filename=null; fromPage='signup'"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="upload-messages" layout="column" laout-align="start center">
                        <div class="imageInvalideMsg" ng-show="imageInvalide">Please choose image of format .jpg, .jpeg, .png, or .gif only</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</md-content>
<md-toolbar class="footer" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
    <h6>&copy; 2015 Urban Life</h6>
</md-toolbar>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

I have a select list on my Angular HTML page,I have used md-select for it.
On change of md-select I get redirected to the another page. 
While loading this second HTML page I am hiding few markup's or elements on this page.

While doing so its giving me this error. Please help, Thanks in Advance.

```
Error : Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

checkIfUpdateProfile function:

```
$scope.checkIfUpdateProfile=function(){
    var params=$location.search();
    console.log("params.EditParam    "+params.EditParam);
    if(params.EditParam){
        $scope.editUserProfile=true;
        $scope.disableName=true;
        $scope.disableMobile=true;
        merchantService.merchantManager
            ._getMerchantData()
            .then(
                function(data) {
                    photoService.showImg=true;
                    merchantService.merchantManager.updateData=data;
                    $scope.user = merchantService.merchantManager.merchant;
                    merchantService.merchantManager.merchant.updateId = data.user.id;
                    $scope.user.firstname = data.user.firstName;
                    $scope.user.middleName = data.user.middleName;
                    $scope.user.lastName = data.user.lastName;
                    $scope.user.eemail = data.user.emailId;
                    $scope.user.telephone = data.user.contactNumber;
                    photoService.signupPath=data.user.photoUrl;
                    $scope.path = photoService.signupPath;
                    $scope.showImg = photoService.showImg;
                },
                function(response) {
                    console.log("Error "+ response);
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code with us

Comment: While loading second page I am doing the rest call and displaying this data on the second page.

Comment: We need your code. Use the "code snippet" tool http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: #sal niro : shared the function which hide's the elemet's  and displays data on page

Comment: The error is occurring in `merchantService.merchantManager._getMerchantData()`, so that's the code we need to see, not your controller code.

Comment: Added merchantService.merchantManager._getMerchantData() function code.

Comment: Test the angularjs v1.4 and v1.2, its look like bootstraping bug

Comment: I love your ng-disabled, hahahaha

Comment: @YOU yeah that is terrible. why `(!something && invalid) || (something && invalid)` that is the same as just `invalid`

Comment: Here is a similar question already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node?rq=1   , but cannot see your codes that actually call the `removeChild`.

Comment: Can you share the code for hiding the elements? That seems to be the culprit