# confuse about the parentNode

Tags: javascript, html

I get confused about the parentNode in JS.Here is my code.

```
<table border="1" width="50%" id="table">
   <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>del</th>
   </tr>  

   <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Kevin</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="del(this);">del</a></td>   
   </tr>
```

and the JS code:

```
function del(obj){
     var tr = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
     tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr)
 }
```

the code works and I think the `obj`  refers to the `<a>` tag, the `obj.parentNode`  refers to the `<td>`tag, the `obj.parentNode.parentNode` refers to the `<tbody>`tag. so the `tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr)` means to remove the `<tr>`tag. Am I right?

the question is that if I change the code like this. It does not work.

```
function del(obj){
     var tr = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
     tr.removeChild(tr)
 }
```

Comment: A node (`tr`) cannot be the a child of itself (`tr`) (unless time travel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why

```
tr.removeChild(tr)
```

doesn't work is because `tr` is not a child of `tr`, i.e. itself. However, `tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr)` works because `tr` is obviously a child of `tr.parentNode`.

Comment: thanks there! can I ask another question? if I want to use `del()` instead of `del(this)` (not very clear know about the "this",I am a beginner) how can I change the `function()`?

Comment: If you don't pass `this` inside del like `del(this)` then inside of it you will have to find clicked TD somehow, not very convenient if TD doesn't have any class or id, etc, something to identify it with document.querySelector method for example. You could however use this `onclick="del.call(this)"` and inside of the function `this` will point to what `obj` is not.

Answer (score 1):

removeChild will look for a node within the node calling the function.  In other words tr.removeChild is looking for tr *inside* of tr.  Try this instead:

```
var tr = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
var trParent = tr.parentNode;
trParent.removeChild(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

> I had to deal with the same issue, and the answer is confusing and
>   counter intuitive. Well, it has its logic, but leads to non-trivial
>   behaviours.
>
> Essentially, when a node is removed from the DOM tree, it fires a blur
>   event (and before a focusout event too).
>
> So, when you call removeChild, the blur event is fired again, but this
>   time link still has its parentNode defined, but link isn't among its
>   parent's children anymore! (Yes, read this twice. Or more.)

Answer from [Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node)

Comment: That seems unrelated to the problem presented here. Also, simply copying an answer is not really tolerated here.