# Bootstrap 4 popover open only ones

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I created a modal window, and it has `a` link with the `focus` I want to show / hide poover:

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">What type of accounts are found?</a>
```

The problem is, that only works one time and further, nothing happens when you click. The script for the popover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

    $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
        trigger: 'focus'
    });

    $('.example-popover').popover({
        container: 'body'
    });
});
```

Someone knows what could be the reason?

Error:  tether.min.js: 1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: @ShiranDror Yes, here is this:
tether.min.js: 1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Here is the solution of the error you get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node

Comment: Please add to you question the elements with the classes ".popover-dismiss" and ".example-popover"

Comment: btw, is the modal content being generated dynamically?

Comment: @ShiranDror These elements are there in the script. 

Content modal windows - the usual login form

Comment: Point is, the problem is not with this specific code. here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/qnx8qxr3/

Comment: Try refreshing the page, is the error still there before you do anything?

Comment: @ShiranDror Yeap, error still here

Comment: do you have any Tether script on your page? something like: new Tether({ ... });

Comment: @ShiranDror No, only have tether.min.js before bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Are you running Tether 1.3.2?

Comment: @zerohero Yes, this was a mistake. I installed 1.3.3 and the problem has been resolved. thank you very much