# setTimeout is needed when 2 events are fired at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have an focus and keydown events. Everytime the input element is out of focus or an enter key is pressed, I update the page to reflect the changes.

The Render class rerenders the currently selected page.

The issue here is that when I update the page with the enter key, both the `focusout` and `kedown` events are fired. This code seems to work only if I give the event's callback a `timeout`.

The question is, is it possible to sovle this "event colission" without `setTimeout` and why does that happen?

```js
// Page content class
const descriptionInput = document.createElement('textarea');
const handleDescription = function(e){
            if( (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) || 
            (e.type === "focusout")
            ){
                task.description = this.value;
                storage.updateTask(task.id, task);
                (new Render).refreshPage()
            }
        }
descriptionInput.addEventListener('keydown', handleDescription)
descriptionInput.addEventListener('focusout', handleDescription)
```

```js
// Render class
renderPage(contentFunction){
        const pastContent = document.querySelector('.content');
        if(pastContent) this.pageContainer.removeChild(pastContent);
        this.pageContainer.appendChild(contentFunction());
    }
refreshPage(){
    const currentPage = document.querySelector('.sidebar li[selected]');
    switch (currentPage.getAttribute('name')) {
        case 'Active Task':
            this.renderPage(activeTasks);
            break;
        case 'Complete Task':
            this.renderPage(completeTask);
            break;
    }
}
```

```js
// No error snippit
if( (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) || 
        (e.type === "focusout")
        ){
            setTimeout(() => {
                task.description = this.value;
                storage.updateTask(task.id, task);
                (new Render).refreshPage()
            }, 100)
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need both event listeners? Pressing Enter in an input causes focus to leave, so the `focusout` event will occur automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Because I need dynamic input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926083/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node), `focusout` is fired when an input is removed from the DOM. What worked for me is removing the event listener.

```js
const handleDescription = function(e){
            if( e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey ){
                descriptionInput.removeEventListener('focusout', handleDescription);
                task.description = this.value;
                storage.updateTask(task.id, task);
                (new Render).refreshPage()
            }
            if(e.type === "focusout")
            {
                task.description = this.value;
                storage.updateTask(task.id, task);
                (new Render).refreshPage()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you focusout by pressing the key. You call function handleDescription twice. To solve this problem, you can use a flag and as long as it is true, the function will not be called again.
now you can remove setTimeout.

```
const descriptionInput = document.createElement('textarea');

let descIsUpdating = false;

const handleDescription = function(e) {

    if (descIsUpdating) {
      return false;
    }

    if ((e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) ||
        (e.type === "focusout")
       ) {
        descIsUpdating = true; // start updating
        task.description = this.value;
        storage.updateTask(task.id, task);
        (new Render).refreshPage();
        descIsUpdating = false; // updating is finished
    }
};

descriptionInput.addEventListener('keydown', handleDescription);
descriptionInput.addEventListener('focusout', handleDescription);
```