# Stop Google translate from activating on webpage

Tags: php, wordpress, google-translate

I am looking for a solution to stop Google Translate from activating on my Wordpress Site. Does any know of `PHP` or a `function` that can be placed on the theme `functions.php` to stop this.

Would prefer a solution that can be placed across the entire theme, rather than by `single-page.php`

[image: Screenshot of Google Translate activating]

Thank you for your time and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable google translate from html in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution and it was rather simple. Within the theme `header.php` I placed

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate"/>
```

This has stopped Google Translate from activating.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to tick it, but you can only tick yourself after 2 days.

Comment: Cheers, I will come back for that.