# <meta name="google" content="notranslate"> not working anymore

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-translate

I am trying to disable google translate on my website, as it is causing issues with datepicker/interface on the website

Google through the web and found that most answers are pointing to [How to disable google translate from html in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome), but just like the comments below it mention, it does not seem to work.

If there is not a way to disable google translate function, maybe there is a way to detect it with JS, and disable functionality on the webpage unless viewed in English?

Answer (score 4):

Use `value` not `content`:

`<meta name="google" value="notranslate" >`

or place directive directly to top `<html>`:

`<html translate="no">`

Comment: translate="no" works inside divs too!

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="notranslate"` to the containing element of the part you don't want to be translated, e.g. `<body class="notranslate">` if you want to apply it to the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning about the small translate icon is causing issues with datepicker/interface on your website.

Actually `notranslate`/`translate="no"` has been not working for a LONG time.

But I found a dirty way to fix this.

JUST HIDE IT.

```css
#gtx-trans{
  display: none;
}
```

work done.