# Can't manage to hide window using if on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

First of all a little background so that you guys don´t respond so harshly, I´ve been learning code for the past month and a half.
I´ve been having trouble hiding a window that shows up if your browser language is not in English. I know there are other ways to go around it but I would like to know why it isn´t working, I just don´t want to give up on it and try to understand it. I want the window to disappear when I press the no button. HERE IS AN IMAGE OF THE WINDOW https://imgur.com/gallery/iTEX0I0
Here is the code:

```js
var lang = navigator.language;
if ("" + lang == "es-US") {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
}
var button = document.getElementById("buttonn")
buttonn.onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("win");
  if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="window" id="win">
      <div class="layover">
        <div class="h2">
          <h2>Oops!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="yesandno">
          <figure class="yes">
            <button onclick="window.location.href= 'espanol.html';">Si</button>
          </figure>
          <figure class="no">
            <button onclick id="buttonn">No</button>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="langmessage">
          Hemos detectado que el idioma de su ordenador se encuentra en español. ¿Le gustaría utilizar la versión en español de nuestro sitio web?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what kinda window shows up can you show us a screenshot? also formatted your code properly

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/iTEX0I0 here is the window showing up

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12238414/9201277

Comment: nope, i just want the window to disappear when i press the no button but it doesnt

Comment: so you want the `iframe` to disappear if that's an iframe in the screenshot, I mean the example that I updated works well no?

Comment: i dont know what an iframe is, i just want to hide the <div class= "window">, which is the div that i used in css to create the window, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a typo on line 6, change `buttonn` to button, see if that works. 
 I have added the snippet that works fine, according to your need.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("buttonn");
buttonn.onclick = function() {
 var div = document.getElementById("win");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="buttonn">No</button>
<div id='win' style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh yeah, i changed it but still doesn´t hide the <div class= "window">

Comment: I tried this code and it works perfectly--
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<button type="button"
id="buttonn">
No</button>
<div id='win' style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>


<script>
var button = document.getElementById("buttonn");
buttonn.onclick = function() {
 var div = document.getElementById("win");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>  
</body>  
</html> 
` Also your code snippet works just fine.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much, i figured thanks to your code that i forgot to add `var div= DOCUMENT.getElementById("win")` on my code

Comment: Happy to help. :) Mark the answer as accepted if that helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that you are checking if the browser language is in fact in English. The English language code is "en-US".  You used "es-US" in an if statement, but that is the language code for Spanish.

Comment: yes, sorry i meant that the window shows up when it detects that yourt  browser language is in spanish