# How to disable auxiliary menu in Chrome “Translate to Portuguese/English”

Tags: html, google-chrome, translate

Is there any way to prevent the "Translate to Portuguese" menu from being displayed on my page?

When triggered, the translation generates embarrassing situations, such as "Customer Code" translated into "Customer Cod".

The post guidelines below remove the translation option from the search bar, but do not remove it from the auxiliary menu. [How to disable google translate from html in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome).

[Image - option for disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8cwJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Settings" -> "Language" -> turn off "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read", see the images below:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Maybe I didn't specify very well, is there a way to disable this on my system with HTML?