# How to prevent Edge from translating a webpage

Tags: html, translation, microsoft-edge

In the last weeks I had some calls from users of my cloud application that tell me, that all labels and buttons do have strange names & descriptions. It turned out that the reason for this is the automatic translation in Microsoft Edge that is activated on their devices.

The problem: we offer a German cloud application and Edge tries to translate German into (really stupid) German. It doesn't care about `<html lang="de">` and tries to translate the complete German page into another German one which is completely stupid and wrong.

How can I prevent this behavior? How can I tell Edge that this page already **is** in German and that it doesn't need to be translated?

This is a really stupid behavior because it completely confuses our users and we get a lot of calls from them that our application is not working correctly.

Comment: Hi @Zu Zhou, I've now implemented both your answers (the meta tag & the additional div), but unfortunately I'm not able to test this because on my Windows VM the translation doesn't seem to be active. So I can only test this on a machine of a client, and the people that had the problem have now deactivated translation. So I need to wait if the problem occurs again or not.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you're using Edge Chromium. Correct me if I guess wrong. `notranslate` class doesn't work for me. You can add this line inside `<head></head>` to disable automatic translation in browser:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

I've tested and it can work well in Edge Chromium and Chrome.

Reference link: [How to disable google translate from html in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome)

Comment: I have used this but its not working Edge

Comment: This in combination with `lang="notranslate"` on the HTML tag works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Add a div like:-

```
<body>
<div class = "notranslate">
<!--Your HTML content here-->
</div>
</body>
```

For more information refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/prevent-translation

Comment: Weird. I put the class in my `<body>` tag, refreshed the page and it worked (Didn't get prompted to translate the page). Then I **removed** the class, refreshed and... the translation message didn't pop up again either. I'm still leaving it there as a good luck charm.

Comment: class="notranslate" works on Edge only if user is on the page and clicks "Translate in ..." in contextual menu, but if he navigates and comes back to the page, annotated div content is translated anyway....