# Diff errors with PageTitle when using google translate in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, google-translate

Many browsers have built in features for translating a page. When users try this in my app however, it results in errors when navigating to a different page. This is the type of error that occurs: (standard diff errors)

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
  Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
      at x (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:17125)
      at M (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:16836)
      at se.insertMarkup (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:24546)
      at se.insertFrame (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:23416)
      at se.applyEdits (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:21490)
      at se.updateComponent (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:20774)
      at https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59513
      at Vt.Ke._internal.renderBatch (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59885)
      at Object.Gt [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://devolv.com/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:62728)
      at Object.Ii (https://devolv.com/_framework/dotnet.7.0.2.85wfq42abb.js:5:71465)
```

<strike>It doesn't occur on all pages however, and I'm thinking it may have to do with if I do things in the `OnAfterRender` lifecycle method.</strike>

I have implemented localization in my app and I'd rather people use that. I looked into ways of preventing the use of google translate through `<html class="notranslate">` and `<meta name="googlebot" content="notranslate">` found in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome), but it didn't appear to work for the on-page translator that the user initializes themselves.

This error can be reproduced on other Blazor sites like [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) by translating and spamming between pages, but it doesn't appear as often as with my site.

Anyone have any clues about ways to prevent this error?

**Edit**: After some investigating, this appears to happen on pages where the `PageTitle` component is used. Removing that component will prevent the error from occurring. I would still like to find some way around this though.