# Dynamically set html's lang attribute still pops up wrong language in Chrome's "Translate this page"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome

We built an Angular web app that, at initial loading, does a HTTP-request to an API to determine the available languages. Then it uses the first language to set the `<html>`'s `lang`-attribute, so, for example, it looks like this: `<html lang="en">`

The problem is that at initial load, before the HTTP-request is completed, the `html`-tag does not have a `lang` attribute and Google Chrome is going to guess (always wrongly) what the language is and shows a "Translate this page" pop-up in the top-right corner. At this time, there isn't even content yet.
We can't set the `lang` attribute initially because we don't know the language of the page yet. We only know that after the first HTTP-request is done.

Adding `<meta name="google" value="notranslate" />` or `<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />` does not prevents the "Translate this page" pop-up from showing up.

How can we make Google Chrome suggesting the right, dynamically set, language to be translated, or prevent the pop-up from showing up at all?

Comment: May be this link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238396/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-html-in-chrome

Comment: We see a similar issue, I believe this is relatively new behaviour in Chrome.