# Enable Chrome translation in my website

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-translate

How do I enable the icon which is shown in chrome´s address bar next to the favorite star?
The site will be in greek but for now I need this icon to appear to make one click translations for non greek speakers.

I added:

```
<html lang="el">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="google" content="translate" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="el-GR" />
```

But nothing..

Basically seems like the opposite to this article
[Disable Chrome translation bar on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228972/disable-chrome-translation-bar-on-my-website).

Thanks

Comment: You may see the icon that I refere in this link http://i.imgur.com/9VrOQt7.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that chrome automatically does this by seeing what your language preference is and then comparing it to the language displayed on the page. No additional code is required.

Comment: try to understand, what OP is about.. it's not about how does GOOGLE translate, but about adding the same feature to their website on own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thats what I thought but this icon is not displayed, I might be missing something...

Comment: Do I need to register the site somewhere? or add a script or something?