# How to Disable Chrome translation bar on my website

Tags: html

I have one client data management website. If I run my website in Chrome and right click Translate to English, it's change my client name (ex. if name is Sourashi Chrome change is to Sourav). How can I disable or remove Translate to English in Chrome for my website? This doesn't work

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" class=notranslate />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Chrome translation bar on my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228972/disable-chrome-translation-bar-on-my-website)

Comment: Linked duplicate for translation bar, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9628507/1207195) for single words/sentences.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Are you sure? "_How can I disable or remove Translate to English in Chrome for my_ **website**"

Comment: @takendarkk but in question he wants to disable translation for specific words (customer name). I'm not sure what he wants then I voted the dupe but also provided link for the other case...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>You cannot remove Chrome translation from your website. The user decides whether he wants to translate your site or not through their browser.</s>

Since this is done client side, you cannot prevent an user from translating your website.

I take that back. Add `class="notranslate"` to your element.

```
<span class="user notranslate">His Name Here</span>
```

That will prevent Chrome from translating his name. If you want to make the entire website untranslatable, you need to do this inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```